# Converting nested lists to dictionary

Tags: python

Hi please I try to make a dictionary out of the nested lists below and I get a TypeError. Please help me fix it to get the desired output as shown below. Thanks

```
n1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
n2 = [[(5,7),(10,22)],[(6,4),(8,11)]]

output = {1:(5,7), 2:(10,22), 3:(6,4), 4:(8,11)}

D1 = {}
for key, value in zip(n1,n2):
    D1[key] = value
print D1 

TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your approach didn't work, because when you zip `n1` and `n2`, the result will be like this

```
for key, value in zip(n1,n2):
    print key, value
# [1, 2] [(5, 7), (10, 22)]
# [3, 4] [(6, 4), (8, 11)]
```

So, `key` is a list. But, it is not hashable. So it cannot be used as an actual key to a dictionary.

You can chain the nested lists to get them flattened and then you can `zip` them together with `izip`

```
from itertools import chain, izip
print dict(izip(chain.from_iterable(n1), chain.from_iterable(n2)))
# {1: (5, 7), 2: (10, 22), 3: (6, 4), 4: (8, 11)}
```

The beauty of this method is that, it will be very memory efficient, as it doesn't create any intermediate lists. So, this can be used even when the actual lists are very large.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not the most pythonic way, but it's short:

```
In [8]: dict(zip(sum(n1, []), sum(n2, [])))
Out[8]: {1: (5, 7), 2: (10, 22), 3: (6, 4), 4: (8, 11)}
```

The `sum()` trick, is used for flattening the list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from itertools import chain
n1 = [[1,2],[3,4]]
n2 = [[(5,7),(10,22)],[(6,4),(8,11)]]
print dict(zip(chain(*n1), chain(*n2))
```