# Converting nested lists to dictionary with self generated keys

Tags: python, dictionary, nested-lists

My list of lists looks like this:

```
my_list = [[sub_list_1],[sub_list_2],...,[sub_list_n]]
```

**Desired output**

```
my_dict[1] = [sub_list_1]
my_dict[2] = [sub_list_2]
my_dict[n] = [sub_list_n]
```

I want the keys for the dictionary to be generated on their own. How can this be achieved in a pythonic way?

I look at certain questions like

- [Converting list of lists in dictionary python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59047263/converting-list-of-lists-in-dictionary-python)
- [Python: List of lists to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34191817/python-list-of-lists-to-dictionary)
- [Converting nested lists to dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22759103/converting-nested-lists-to-dictionary)

but they either provide a list of keys or focus on using some information from the lists as keys.

Alternatively, I tried making a list of keys this way:

```
my_keys = list(range(len(my_list)))
my_dict = dict(zip(my_keys,my_list)
```

*and it works* **but**, this does not:

```
my_dict = dict(zip(list(range(len(my_list))),my_list))
```

This gives me a syntax error.

So in summary:

- Is there a way to generate a dictionary of lists without explicitly providing keys?, and
- Why does the combined code throw a syntax error whereas the two step code works?

Comment: More details on the error? `my_dict = dict(zip(list(range(len(my_list))),my_list))` worked just fine for me.

Comment: my_dict = dict(zip(list(range(len(my_list))), my_list))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: this worked fine for me as well (copy-pasted from your comment):  
  
```my_list = [["hello1"], ["hello2"]]
my_dict = dict(zip(list(range(len(my_list))), my_list))
```

Comment: are you able to provide us with a bit more code? There shouldnt be anything wrong with that line.

Comment: edited question to add error screen shot

Comment: `try` is a reserved word in python (try-catch statement)

Comment: See my answer for links to the try/except statement. As @JustinMai mentions, this is a reserved "name" in python, which cannot be assigned to a value. You can use `Try` or `TRY`

Comment: `my_dict = {n: sublist for n, sublist in enumerate(my_list, start=1)}`

Comment: Please do not share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode, https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/.

Comment: oh sorry, removed the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use a dict comprehension to achieve what you want like in here, moreover I tried your implementation and haven't faced any issues (more details are more than welcome):

```
my_list = [["sub_list_1"],["sub_list_2"],["sub_list_3"]]
my_dict = dict(zip(list(range(len(my_list))),my_list))
alternative_dict = {iter:item for iter,item in enumerate(my_list)}
print("yours : " + str(my_dict))
print("mine : " + str(alternative_dict))
```

output:

```
yours : {0: ['sub_list_1'], 1: ['sub_list_2'], 2: ['sub_list_3']}
mine : {0: ['sub_list_1'], 1: ['sub_list_2'], 2: ['sub_list_3']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax error is caused by your variable name `try`. `try` is allready a name in python. see [try/except](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_try_except.asp)

Answer (score 1):

I received no error message when running your code:

```py
>>> my_list = [["hello1"], ["hello2"]]
>>> my_dict = dict(zip(list(range(len(my_list))), my_list))
>>> my_dict
{1: ['hello1'], 2: ['hello2']}
```

You can create a dict of lists from a list of lists using a dict comprehension:

```py
my_dict = {i: sub_list for i, sub_list in enumerate(my_list)}
```

Comment: > Is there a way to generate a dictionary of lists without explicitly providing keys?

Comment: he's actually asking both; you answered the syntax error portion and I showed how to make a dict of lists from list of lists without defined keys.

Comment: Yeah, I read the question again. Please excuse my mistake. Although you didn't really provide any explanation for your code either.

Comment: no worries we're humans. and Yossi's answer has both the syntax error portion and the implementation portion of the question so it's technically more correct. i just don't like how the single line of code needed is buried in other explanatory lines but oh well

Comment: I understand, I just believe there is more value in providing OP with the knowledge of answering the question as well as the answer. EDIT: Thank you for your edit! Looks great

Comment: Hi Justin, i did not downvote. Maybe someone else.  I just want to get over with this and sleep ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```py
my_dict = {my_list.index(i) + 1: i for i in my_list}
```

Notice that I have added `+1` to start at the key 1 instead of 0 to match your expectations

Comment: i believe using `.index()` will be slower than `enumerate(list)`

Comment: That is the contrally. Enumerate checks for the index and value at the same time. Hence the `.index` solution is 1/3 faster than using `enumerate` as the latter solution checks the value 2 times.

Comment: oh! interesting, thank you. what's the name of the "law" where you'll find the correct answer quickest by publishing the incorrect answer? :)